# JAX RS(Jersey 1.19 ) not able to call Filter

Tags: java, rest, filter, jersey, jax-rs

Below is mine Filter

```
    package com.rest.echidna.filter;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

@Provider
public class CustomRestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest arg0) {
        System.out.println("CustomRestFilter.filter()");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Controller-->

```
package com.rest.echidna.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.rest.echidna.model.User;
import com.rest.echidna.model.UserList;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.Status;

@Path(value = "/user/")
public class UserRestController {

    private static final List<User> usersDB = new ArrayList<User>();

    static {
        System.out.println("Inside JERSEY");
        usersDB.add(new User("A", 26, "SSE"));
        usersDB.add(new User("B", 28, "SSE"));
        usersDB.add(new User("C", 29, "TA"));
        usersDB.add(new User("D", 31, "TA"));
        usersDB.add(new User("E", 35, "TL"));

    }

    @Path(value = "/getAllUser")
    @GET
    public Response getAllUsers(@HeaderParam(value = "Accept") String ht ) {
System.out.println(ht);

        return Response.status(Status.OK).header("A", 123).entity(new UserList(usersDB)).build();

    }

    @Path(value = "/getAllUser/{name}")
    @GET
    public User getUser(@PathParam("name") String name,@Context HttpHeaders ht) {
        for(Entry<String, List<String>> m:ht.getRequestHeaders().entrySet()){
            System.out.println(m.getValue());
        }
        User resultUser = null;
        for (User u : usersDB) {
            if (u.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                resultUser = u;
            }
        }

        return resultUser;
    }

    @Path(value = "/getAllUser/{name}")
    @DELETE
    public UserList deleteUser(@PathParam("name") String name) {

        Iterator<User> it = usersDB.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (it.next().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }

        return new UserList(usersDB);
    }

    @Path(value = "/getAllUser/create")
    @POST
    public UserList createUser(User user) {

        System.out.println(user);
        usersDB.add(user);

        return new UserList(usersDB);
    }

    @Path(value = "/getAllUser/{name}")
    @PUT
    public UserList createUser(@PathParam("name") String name, User user) {

        User tempUser = null;
        Iterator<User> it = usersDB.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            tempUser = it.next();
            if (tempUser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                tempUser.setAge(user.getAge());
                tempUser.setRole(user.getRole());

                it.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
        usersDB.add(tempUser);
        return new UserList(usersDB);
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>RESTAPIJersey1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file/>

  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.rest.echidna</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.echidna.filter.CustomRestFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Jars-->
[image: JARS]

I have commented the Filter params or even if i remove the comment it will not work.
After hitting the url is not calling the Filter but the main controller is getting called.I have googled it but didn't able to find appropriate solution for Jersey 1.19 Filter.Please help!!!

URL to hit in local server-->
http://localhost:8080/RESTJersey/rest/user/getAllUser

Answer (score 0):

Your init param name is not correct

Please change it from

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter
```

to

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters
```

Update:

Here are the changes made to your project shown above

- Add dependency `jersey-grizzly2`

As per [Jersey 1](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/1.19.1/getting-started.html), you need have two dependency for your project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

- You need to return the same request object in your `CustomRestFilter`. I have updated it your question.
- Please correct your code around how you want to return the `UserList` object. If you want to return it as `json`, then please look [here](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/1.19.1/json.html)

This is how I am able to see it on my console:

```
09-Aug-2017 19:24:02.503 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-32] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
CustomRestFilter.filter()
Inside JERSEY
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Comment: No i have changed it to com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters but no use.Not getting any output in console.

Comment: Can you please update the complete `web.xml` and `CustomRestFilter.java`?

Comment: I have updated everything .Any help i dont want to use Jersey 2 if it can be done with Jersey 1.19 .Everywhere the signature of filter method is different i:e it is void but when i am implementing it is returning ContainerRequest .You can try the same in ur local and please suggest .

Comment: Thanks for the jersey-grizzle jar.But UserList is ok as i have to written the list of user.So list of user will not work i guess so just a wrapper.

Comment: Does your filter getting called now?

Comment: Yes Thanks I known I was missing some jar

Comment: Great to hear that